# How to store a not partly unique primary key in a data vault?

Tags: database, database-design, data-vault

I've got a problem with trying to transfer a data model to a data vault. I've tried a lot already but cannot figure out the correct way of identifying the hubs, links and satellites for this part of the diagram.

[image]

What is shown is a employee that works at a certain store. The issue here is the the employee_id on it's own does not uniquely identify a employee. Two employees can have employee_id 1 as long as they are working in different stores.

What would be the correct method of modelling this (what should be the hub, links and satellites)?

Answer (score 0):

A business key can have more than one field.

In this case, the business key can be the store and the employe id (if you can have another field than an ID that uniquely identify the store and the employee that the end user can remember, it will be better).